# Data on radio station tower locations in Africa

Tags: geospatial, africa

Hey I am wondering if it exists somewhere a public access dataset or map of radio tower location for African countries. I am interested in towers transmitting signals in AM/FM waves for radio stations.

I would be particularly interested in Liberia but any other country could work. I would be looking for something like latitude and longitude, owner and signal range.

Answer (score 3):

[OpenCellid](https://opencellid.org/) is an open cell tower database offered by Unwired Labs and claims to be "The world's largest Open Database of Cell Towers".  You simply need to sign up for an API key to access the data via an API or as a dump.  The data is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International License.

Comment: I used this in the past but isn't it only about cellphone towers? I am looking for radio station towers. Unless they are the same, I am not an expert

Comment: Ah yes, I thought that might be a problem.  I'm no expert either but from what I understand some cell towers may also operate with frequencies (e.g. AM / FM frequency) but this seems not to be captured in the OpenCellid database.  Can you edit your original post to be more precise about what you mean by "radio" (e.g. frequency or type of communication)?

Answer (score 2):

Open Street Map [has some data on radio towers](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/POo).